# How to group Controller using route namespace Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, namespaces

I am working on laravel project i have completed my admin panel and my all conrollers are in namespace App\Http\Controllers and everything is working perfectly fine now but i want to move all my Controller in folder AdminController for making everything more clear and smooth(Kind of HMVC technique).For this I add namespace on route which I did something like this

```
  Route::group(['prefix' =>'admin','namespace'=>'AdminController'], function ()
    {
/// all route
    });
```

and i move all my conrollers in folder AdminController.Now its giving me error **Cannot redeclare class Chemist\Http\Controllers\RoleController**

**Note:** My baseconroller are in director `App\Http\Controllers` and all other controller are in `App\Http\Controllers\AdminController`

Comment: Please post the full error message. Or just look at it, it should tell you also where exactly the class is already defined.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom controller dir like

```
php artisan make:controller subDriectory/YourController
php artisan make:controller subDriectory/YourController --plain
```

Comment: that does not solve author's issue with *moving existing controllers*.